# Writing a string (with new lines) in Python

Tags: python

I have to write strings with newlines and a specific structure to files in Python. When I do

```
 stringtowrite = "abcd ||
                   efgh||
                   iklk"

f = open(save_dir + "/" +count+"_report.txt", "w")
f.write(stringtowrite)
f.close()
```

I'm getting this error:

> SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

How can I write the string as it is to a file without deleting the new lines?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you tried to modify your string the following way:

```
stringtowrite = "abcd ||\nefgh||\niklk"

f = open(save_dir + os.path.sep +count+"_report.txt", "w")
f.write(stringtowrite)
f.close()
```

OR:

```
stringtowrite = """abcd ||
                   efgh||
                   iklk"""
```

Answer (score 10):

The simplest thing is to use python's triple quotes (note the three single quotes)

```
stringtowrite = '''abcd ||
                   efgh||
                   iklk'''
```

any string literal with triple quotes will continue on a following line. You can use ''' or """.

By the way, if you have

```
a = abcd
b = efgh
c = iklk
```

I would recommend the following:

```
stringtowrite = "%s||\n%s||\n%s" % (a,b,c)
```

as a more readable and pythonic way of doing it.

Comment: Note you'll also get the leading whitespace using this.

Comment: Otherwise you'd have to do it all in one line: `'abcd ||\nefgh||\niklk'`

Comment: Yep. I anticipate some further data format debugging for the author once this works. :)

Answer (score 5):

You can add the `\` character to the end of each line, which indicates that the line is continued on the next line, you can triple-quote the string instead of single-quoting it, or you can replace the literal newlines in the string with `\n`.

Comment: Putting a line continuation `\\` at the end of the line will ***not*** embed a newline - it will just append the text from the next line.

Answer (score 4):

You can write newlines – `\n` – into your string.

```
stringtowrite = "abcd ||\nefgh||\niklk"
```

Comment: Actually, the method from which I get an array of strings spits out strings with newlines. How do I replace each newline in the array of strings with '\' ?

Comment: If there are already newlines, there would be no need to add them - but then, I don't know your setup.